# MUI ListItem href prop not hitting my api routes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui, passport.js

I have a node js backend for my api routes and i am using Passport js for my authenticaion.

Im facing an issue at the moment to hit my api route to log out the user. What scratches my head is, if i used a Button component with the href prop and manually enter the full endpoint url, that works.

If i used a ListItem component, it doesnt do anything.

```
<ListItem button href='http://localhost:5000/auth/logout'>
   <ListItemIcon>
      <LogoutIcon color='secondary' />
   </ListItemIcon>
   <ListItemText primary='Logout' />
</ListItem>
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add component="a" at ListItem and then the link will working fine.
You can try my code:

```js
<ListItem button component="a" href='http://localhost:5000/auth/logout'>
   <ListItemIcon>
      <LogoutIcon color='secondary' />
   </ListItemIcon>
   <ListItemText primary='Logout' />
</ListItem>
```

Comment: Thank you this works. I found another solution using the window object i reckon your solution is cleaner

Comment: @HenryDinh Hi, if you feel my answer works for you, please flag my answer be the best answer, thank you.